# reducelist in Python: like reduce but giving the list of intermediate results

Tags: python, list, functional-programming, reduce

You know the handy `reduce` function in Python. For example, you could use it to sum up a list like so (pretend there isn't the built-in [sum](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum)):

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [1,2,3,4], 0)
```

which returns (((0+1)+2)+3)+4 = 10.

Now what if I wanted a list of the intermediate sums? In this case, `[1,3,6,10]`.

Here's an ugly solution. Is there something more pythonic?

```
def reducelist(f, l, x): 
  out = [x]
  prev = x
  for i in l:
    prev = f(prev, i)
    out.append(prev)
  return out
```

Comment: FYI, at least in Haskell this is known as *scan*. Reduce is also known as (a specific kind of) *fold* in the functional programming world.

Comment: Thanks delnan, yeah, I know this as FoldList from Mathematica. Mathematica has an accumulating version of a lot of these functional programming functions, denoted by appending "List". I see from the answer below that in Python 3 what I call reducelist is now available as accumulate().

Answer (score 18):

My favourite, if you're recent enough:

```
Python 3.2.1 (default, Jul 12 2011, 22:22:01) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.accumulate([1,2,3,4])
<itertools.accumulate object at 0x1006baad0>
>>> list(itertools.accumulate([1,2,3,4]))
[1, 3, 6, 10]
```

[accumulate](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) also accepts a function argument [even more recent, though-- 3.3]:

```
>>> list(itertools.accumulate([1,2,3,4], lambda x,y: x+y))
[1, 3, 6, 10]
>>> list(itertools.accumulate([1,2,3,4], lambda x,y: x+y+1))
[1, 4, 8, 13]
```

Comment: Ah, nice! Though for me this is both too recent (I'm in Python 2) and too specific (this is just for summing, not the general reducelist thing I'm looking for). EDIT: Ah, it *is* general enough, with that optional argument; thanks!

Comment: Nice. +1. Wish I saw this before spent the time writing my own answer.

Comment: Itertools accumulate recipe https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate

Answer (score 9):

If you make your solution to a generator it's shorter and it better obeys functional programming style. I would add an default value of 0 for x too:

```
def reducelist(f, lst, x=0): 
  prev = x
  for i in lst: 
    prev = f(prev, i)
    yield prev
```

That is definitely more *pythonic*.

Comment: Thanks! What if you needed to return an actual list? Can we do the conversion here within the function? Would that still be better than constructing the list by repeatedly appending?

Comment: I would leave it to the user of the function to convert the generator to a list with `list` function. If you want a function that directly returns a list you could make a helper function `reducelist_helper(f,lst,x=0): return list(reducelist(f,lst,x))`

Answer (score 1):

Note: Somehow I missed @DSM's answer before I wrote this. Go read and up vote that one instead, I just did. Come back if you want a longer answer.

Python has this, it's called accumulate and it's implemented in the itertools standard library module starting in Python 3.2. The optional second argument, 'func', was added in 3.3.

```
import itertools

l = [1,2,3,4]
out = itertools.accumulate(l)
```

In this case `out` is an iterable. If you need a list, then

```
out = list(itertools.accumulate(l))
```

The `accumulate()` function can be used to generate a running total, or 'accumulated sums'. The default function is addition. We can pass in a function as the second argument:

```
import itertools
import operator

l = [1,2,3,4]
factorial = itertools.accumulate(l, operator.mul)
```

Here we pass in operator.mul for multiplication to generate a running product. The `operator` module exports a set of efficient functions corresponding to the intrinsic operators of Python.

Of course we're not limited to functions defined in the `operator` module. You can use any function that accepts 2 parameters of the type of the elements in the first parameter. You can get creative, but here I'll do the opposite and explicitly implement the default addition/sum behavior using a lambda:

```
import itertools

l = [1,2,3,4]
out = itertools.accumulate(l, lambda a, b: a + b)
```

Finally, since you asked, I think using `accumulate` is more Pythonic then your looping example.