# I am confused about the time complexity of my algorithm

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have designed an algorithm but confused whether the time complexity is theta(n) or theta (n^2).

```
def prefix_soms(number):
    Array_A=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    Array_B=[]
    soms=0
    for i in range(0,number):
        soms=soms+Array_A[i]
        Array_B.insert(i,soms)
    return Array_B[number-1]
```

I know the for loop is running n times  so that's O(n).

Is the inside operations O(1)?

Comment: For arbitrary large numbers, it is not, since adding two huge numbers takes logarithmic time in the *value* of these numbers. For non-huge numbers, it is ok. But you can make your can make your code more elegant.

Comment: You can take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073596/what-is-the-cost-complexity-of-insert-in-list-at-some-location

Comment: Would say inside list insertion operation is O(n) (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073596/what-is-the-cost-complexity-of-insert-in-list-at-some-location)

Comment: @DarrylG: `.insert(..)` is *O(n)* with *n* the elements at the right side of the insertion point. Since we here always append at the right end, it is just an `.append(..)` (but I agree it is not elegant at all)

Comment: @DarrylG: No, since we insert at the *end* of the list, here, so an `.insert(last_index, value)` will still run in amortized cost *O(1)* :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, you're right.  I hadn't noticed he was inserting at the end of the list which would be constant time as you say.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem do you agree that a better faster method for what he's doing (i.e. performing an accumulation and maintaining intermediate results) is to use itertools.accumulate per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233788/reducelist-in-python-like-reduce-but-giving-the-list-of-intermediate-results?

Comment: @DarryIG: yes of course there are faster ways than using an extra list. Especially since this will consume extra memory, and hence can increase the amount of cache faults, etc. But time complexity-wise it does not change the performance. Of course time complexity does not take "details" into account such as cache faults, etc.

Comment: If one of the answers is helpful for you, you can accept it as the answer by clicking the tick icon at the left side and under the voting number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arbitrary large numbers, it is not, since adding two huge numbers takes logarithmic time in the *value* of these numbers. If we assume that the sum will not run out of control, then we can say that it runs in *O(n)*. The `.insert(…)` is basically just an `.append(…)`. The *amortized* cost of appending *n* items is *O(n)*.

We can however improve the readablility, and memory usage, by writing this as:

```
def prefix_soms(number):
    Array_A=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    soms=0
    for i in range(0,number):
        soms += Array_A[i]
    return soms
```

or:

```
def prefix_soms(number):
    Array_A=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    return sum(Array_A[:number])
```

or we can omit creating a copy of the list, by using `islice(..)`:

```
from itertools import islice

def prefix_soms(number):
    Array_A=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    return sum(islice(Array_A, number))
```

We thus do not need to use another list, since we are only interested in the last item.

Comment: @DeepSpace: it is of course a bit sad, that Python does not have list *fusion* (well I think it might be fundamentally impossible to implement that in a language that has mutable objects), and thus could indeed use slicing without overhead :)

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `insert` method doesn't shift your array - that is as to your algorithm it solely appends one element to end of the list - its time 
complexity is `O(1)`. Moreover, accessing an element with index takes `O(1)` time as well.

You run number of `number` time a loop with some `O(1)`s. `O(number)*someO(1)s = O(number)`

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of `list.insert` is O(n), as shown on [this wiki page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).  You can check the [`blist`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/) library which provides an optimized list type that has an O(log n) insert, but in your algorithm I think that the item is always placed at the end of the Array_B, so it is just an `append` which takes constant amortized time (You can replace the `insert` with `append` to make the code more elegant).